Comparing the volatilities of a strip of options to a terminal option's volatility
Imagine a strip of European options on a Future, each expiring every business day for the next year, for which I have implied volatilities.
I also have a single European option expiring the same day as the last of these options.
I am interested in knowing the worth of the strip vs the worth of the terminal option, in terms of volatilities.
In essence the question boils down to hedging exotics with vanilla exchange options.
